# Handling null values Hazelcast Projections

Tags: java, hazelcast

How to handle null values in the hazelcast projections

```
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
IMap<Integer, HazelcastJsonValue> map = hz.getMap("myMap");

map.set(0, new HazelcastJsonValue("{\"id\":\"01\",\"name\":\"abc\",\"age\":null}"));
map.set(1, new HazelcastJsonValue("{\"id\":\"02\",\"name\":\" data\",\"age\":37} "));
map.set(2, new HazelcastJsonValue("{\"id\":\"03\",\"name\":\"abc\",\"age\":39}"));

Collection<Object[]> projection = map.project(Projections.multiAttribute("id", "name","age"));
```

In the above code you can observe that age field is null for the first entry so Projections is throwing exception.
How to just return the null value inside of throwing exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Hazelcast version are you using?

I've tried with 4.0.2. I've added the following snippet to print the elements:

```java
projection.stream()
          .flatMap(Stream::of)
          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It outputs the following:

```
03
abc
39
01
abc
null
02
 data
37
```